# Deriving a distribution from the line generated from a point in a uniformly distributed circle and its origin

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $a,r>0$ be two fixed numbers. A random point $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the circle {$(x,y) : x^2+(y-a)^2 = r^2$} with the centre of the circle at $(0,a)$. A line is drawn through $(X,Y)$ and $(0,a)$ and the line intersects the $x$ axis at some point $(\zeta, 0)$.

How would I find the distribution function and the density function of $\zeta$?

After thinking about it and sketching it out my intuitive guess is that $\zeta$ follows a normal distribution with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma^2 = a$, although I'm not quite sure that this is correct. Would someone be able to give me a hint on how to start the problem if I am correct, and if I'm wrong would you be kind enough to give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: It's bell-shaped, but there are many bell-shaped distributions that are not normal distributions, so even if this one were normal you would have to _show_ that it is normal using exact mathematics (rather than merely looking at a graph) in order to make that conclusion--and in this case it isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ the angle that $\frac{Y}{X}=\tan \alpha$. $\alpha$ is uniformly distributed and $\zeta=a \tan \alpha $ which lead us easily to compute the distribution of $\zeta$. Let $F$ the cumulative distribution function of $\zeta$.
$$F(t)=Pr(a \tan \alpha < t)=Pr(\alpha < \arctan\frac{t}{a})=\frac{\arctan \frac{t}{a}+ \frac{\pi}{2}}{\pi}$$ because the $\tan$ is a monotone increasing function. $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of the famous Cauchy distribution. Its mean is indeed 0 but its variance isn't finite.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on your answer? I'm kind of stuck on what to do. I derived the marginal densities of $X$ and $Y$ but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: My hint shows that you doesn't need the marginal densities of X and Y.

Comment: I let $P(Z\le z) = P(Y \le \frac{xz}{a}) = P(Y \le \frac{xz}{a}) = \int_{-\sqrt{(r^2-(y-a)^2)}}^{\sqrt{(r^2-(y-a)^2)}}\int_{\sqrt{(r^2-x^2)+a}}^{ \frac {zX}{a}}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}dydx$ am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: Is Z the new name of $\zeta$? :) My hint was roughly: $P(Y<Xz/a)=P(Y/X<z/a) $  where we know $\arctan Y/X$ is uniformly distributed over the intervall $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Ahh I can't do it this is bugging me so much! And yes Z is $ \zeta $ sorry for the change.

Comment: Wouldn't we be find the distribution of α, not $ \zeta $ itself?

Comment: We computed the distribution of $\zeta$ from $\alpha$'s. Why is $\alpha$ uniformly distributed? Let $\varphi=(0,0)(0,a)(X,Y)\angle$. The distribution of $P=(X,Y)$ is uniform on the circle, it means that the probability that P is on a certain arc is proportional to the length of the arc. As we know from elementary geometry the length of arc corresponding to $\varphi$ is proportional to $\varphi$, hence $\varphi$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. $\alpha=\varphi$ if $|\varphi|<\pi/2$ and $\alpha=-\varphi$ if $|\varphi|\geq\pi/2$, so also $\alpha$ is uniformly distributed.

Comment: And unfortunately I solved your problem instead give you a push into the right direction as you asked. But I hope it wasn't totally useless. If you would like I'll tell you a similar problem to practice.

Comment: Yes please would you give me another problem? That would greatly help me in understanding this topic

Comment: Let $(X,Y)$ point in the plane normally distributed such that its density is $\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^2}\exp(-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2\sigma^2})$. Let $\theta$ the angle between the vector $(X,Y)$ and the $x$-axis. What is the distribution of $\theta$?